# Slugify the url in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

We upload files to Amazon AWS S3 server and use the file url in java class files to provide the functionality of downloading files.

if i upload the file as "*Test Automated Report Sheet.pdf*" (containing spaces between words) then the url for that is

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.generalsentiment.com/MVR/reports/Test+Automated+Report+Sheet1.pdf

I am getting ArrayIndex Out of bound exception as the url contains '+' sign, therefore am replacing the '+' sign again with whitespace. here is the code for doing that. 
I am using

```
String reportURL = mediaValueReport.getReportFileURL().replace('+', ' ');
```

Is this approach fine or can i write it a more optimal way.

Comment: Could you please tell us where the error lies? You have mentioned ArrayIndexOutOfBOund. I would start there, since downloading content using encoded URL is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do this manually . It is a standard for encoding and decoding of URL.

There are many helper liberaies that you can use e.g [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

Comment: String reportURL1 = mediaValueReport.getReportFileURL();
String reportURL = reportURL1.substring(reportURL1.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, reportURL1.length());
String url = reportURL1.substring(0, reportURL1.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
                + URLEncoder.encode(reportURL, "UTF-8");                                                                      But its replacing "+" with "+2B" which is not a valid URL..

Comment: Are you using same class for both encoding and decoding? you should be. in other words you should encode the URL before sending and then decoe.